# Unexpected behavior with 'ansible-playbook --limit' and regular expression with lookahead

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following test setup and result:

```ini
$ cat hosts
[test]
abc-1
abc-ecs
abc-x
ecs-1
ecs-y
```

```yaml
$ cat test-regex.yaml 
- name: test
  hosts:
    - test
  tasks:
    - name: set var
      set_fact:
        myvar: "this is a test"
```

```bash
$ cat hosts | sed "s: ::g" | ggrep -P '^(?!ecs).*'
[test]
abc-1
abc-ecs
abc-x
```

```bash
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts -l ~'^(?!ecs).*' test-regex.yaml -D -C --list-hosts --list-tasks
```

```yaml
playbook: test-regex.yaml

  play #1 (test): test  TAGS: []
    pattern: ['test']
    hosts (5):
      abc-ecs
      abc-x
      ecs-1
      ecs-y
      abc-1
    tasks:
      set var   TAGS: []
```

As shown with `ggrep`, `^(?!ecs).*` does not match `ecs-1` and `ecs-y`, but Ansible says it matches, can you explain?

I would like to apply to hosts starting with `ecs` only. I tested with Ansnile Core 2.13.3.

Also for testing purpose, can I maintain one file instead of two as shown here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question of the original post asks why `-l ~'^(?!ecs).*'` matches every host in the test group:

```
[test]
abc-1
abc-ecs
abc-x
ecs-1
ecs-y
```

but not those three `abc-*` hosts only as intended. This is because `-l ~'^(?!ecs).*'` not only matches hosts, but groups as well, and ansible creates two default groups: `all` and `ungrouped`. In this case, the regular expression matches:

- `test` group which contains all 5 hosts listed above
- `all` group which contains all 5 hosts listed above
- `ungrouped` group which contains 0 hosts
- `abc-1` host
- `abc-x` host
- `abc-ecs` host

The union of all above consists the 5 hosts as shown in the output in the original post, so this is an expected behavior. To get what I intended, which is every hosts not starting with ecs, I should exclude the `test` and `all` groups also. The regular expression and the intended result are copied below.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts -l ~'^(?!ecs|test|all).*' test-regex.yaml -D -C --list-hosts --list-tasks

playbook: test-regex.yaml

  play #1 (test): regexcheck    TAGS: []
    pattern: ['test']
    hosts (3):
      abc-1
      abc-x
      abc-ecs
    tasks:
      set var   TAGS: []
```

The "mystery" resolved.

Comment: My answer was incorrectly marked as "not useful" but I can assure you this answer is correct and verifiable. I spent time writing this answer after I tried very hard and finally figured out with the help of an Ansible employee for those who may encounter the same issue in the future. I request your support by marking it as useful if found so. Thank you.